# AspectJ: Implement only the methods of some Classes

Tags: java, interface, aspectj, aop

I have several classes implementing some interface:

```
public interface SomeName
{
    //some method
}
```

Is it possible to implement this 'some method' in an aspect but choose for which classes will do so?

Comment: how are you thinking of specifying the list of classes that need this method and/or the list of classes that dont need this method at compile time?

Comment: I know that some will definitely not need it but the interface has  also other methods which will be needed. In any case, does aspectj support this?

Comment: as an out of the box feature no, but you can fake it quite easily. create a `interface SomeNameOverride extends SomeName`, for all the classes that need the method, declare them as implementing `SomeNameOverride`, have aspectj do an intertype declaration on that.